# Call a Jquery function to start from php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

In my PHP I am returning and updating a online users box however as it Echos each line out I also want it to activate a Jquery function. So if there is data there it will then echo it out and a Jquery function will take place.

example of php code ...

```
if($count1 > 0) {

foreach (user_list($user_name) as $user){
       echo $user . "<br />";

};
    echo ;// a message to activate a jquery function called userdisplay;
};
```

and the jquery code would look something like this...

```
    function userdisplay(){
   //do some amazing code like slide picture in from left fade text in at the top etc. 


    };
```

#### (I am not asking for help on the code which the function will do this is just an example)

Many thanks to anyone with an idea of how i should go about this my mind is completely blank.

Comment: Post your code here, make it more clear.

Comment: One question per question please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just echo the call to the jquery function between a `<script>` tagfor example:

this is the page:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    //some jquery code here 
});

//here is your function
function userdisplay(){
    alert("triggered");
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
....
<?php
if($count1 > 0) {
    foreach (user_list($user_name) as $user){
        echo $user . "<br />";

    };
        echo "<script>userdisplay();</script>";
}; 
?>
....
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I believed my question was clear enough without code but there you go if that would help.

Comment: I updated the answer according to your code, the question was clear

Answer (score 0):

```
if($count1 > 0) {

foreach (user_list($user_name) as $user){
       echo $user . '<br />';

};
    echo '<script>userdisplay();</script>';
};
```

You just have to make sure the function userDisplay() has been "echoed" before.